# what is the correct syntax for onclick in javascript for a <a> tag settings it's attribute "target"

Tags: css, html, onclick, target

simple div tag that links to something. can't seem to figure how to open the page in a different tab for the onclick attribute

```
var site_name = 'http://www.somesite.com'
var link = 'location.href='"+ site_name +"'

document.getElementById(div_name).setAttribute('onclick',link);
```

if i was using an a tag i would just set the target to blank but other then that i'm lost.

```
document.getElementById(divTagName).setAttribute('target','_blank');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById(div_name).onclick = "window.open('" + site_name + "')";
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot ankur. didn't expect such a fast reply. Save me a lot of time. ^__^!